# Connection reset when trying to tunnel http/socks by multi-hop ssh

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, socks-proxy, http-proxy

**Involved machines:** (client)A -- B -- C(exit)
A/B is cygwin ssh/sshd, C is linux

**What I want:**

1. A's http(s) *and* socks traffic be tunneled through B,C.
   Destination is *any* IP, so -L alone doesn't work.
2. A -- B, B -- C traffic must be encrypted. (So I try to use ssh)

**What I did the setup:**

1. Proxy server(3proxy) running at C: http(s) at 3998, socks5 at 3999.
   I tested the proxy server. working for both 127.0.0.1 and external IP.
2. ssh command on A: (I want to forward local :3998 to C:3998, local :3999 to C:3999)
       ssh -At -L 3998:B:6998 userB@B ssh -At -L 6998:C:3998 userC@C
       ssh -At -L 3999:B:6999 userB@B ssh -At -L 6999:C:3999 userC@C
   I tested the multi-hop login: working.
3. Use 127.0.0.1:3998 as http(s) proxy. Use 127.0.0.1:3999 as socks proxy.

**Problem:**
Firefox is not working with either http or socks, complaining that connection is reset.
(cygwin)wget is not working with http

Error message like "channel 8: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused" is showing on C's ssh console.

**Details with -vvv:**

```
on A:
   $ export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3998; wget www.bing.com
   --2014-04-13 08:54:14--  http://www.bing.com/
   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3998... connected.
   Proxy request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in        headers.
   Retrying.

on C:
   root@C:~# debug1: Connection to port 3998 forwarding to B port 6998 requested.
   debug2: fd 9 setting TCP_NODELAY
   debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
   debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
   channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
   debug2: channel 3: zombie
   debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
   debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3998 for B port 6998, connect
    from 127.0.0.1 port 65460 to 127.0.0.1 port 3998, nchannels 4
   debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
     #2 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 6/7 cc -1)
```

I also tried forwarding in C alone:

```
(one tty) ssh -vvv -L 127.0.0.1:1234:127.0.0.1:3998 root@127.0.0.1
(another tty) export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3998; wget www.bing.com
```

It worked, and I am even confused why it didn't work in my setup.

=================================================================================
If I use this command, then it works?!

```
ssh -At -L 3998:127.0.0.1:6998 userB@B ssh -At -L 6998:127.0.0.1:3998 userC@C
```

But these doesn't work

```
ssh -At -L 3998:ip_of_B:6998 userB@B ssh -At -L 6998:ip_of_C:3998 userC@C
ssh -At -L 3998:ip_of_B:6998 userB@B ssh -At -L 6998:127.0.0.1:3998 userC@C
```

Could someone explain it to me?

I have no idea how openssh implements -L so that it behaves so weird.